# Search on two number fields in Atlas Search

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I have mongo document like this:

```
{
 "pw" : [
   {
     "id" : 123,
     "qty" : 10
   },
   {
     "id" : 456,
     "qty" : 15
   }

 ]
}
```

Id and qty is Number type in Atlas Search.
I want to search like "id = 123" and qty > 5.

**I USED EQUALS and RANGE operator for this, but it is not working. How can I set criteria for specific document level (not in array level)?**

Comment: Is this what you need? https://mongoplayground.net/p/hyf39DIbjvs

Comment: @RubénVega Nope

Comment: Nice! I'm sure we could help with all the additional info xD

Comment: Looks like you are trying to query based on numeric criteria nested in an array. I do not believe that's supported today in Atlas Search.